# Wait for function to run before moving on in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, promise

I have a function `fetchItems()` which extracts items from an API.

In React, I want to set a state and after running `fetchItems()`, I want to set a state again.

Right now, I am just doing it like this

```
onRefresh() {
  this.setState({
    refreshing: true
  }, () => {
    this.props.fetchItems();
    this.setState({
      refreshing: false
    });
  });
}
```

but since it's not called asynchronously, it is not waiting for `fetchItems()` to run before setting the state again.

My function `fetchItems()` looks like this

```
export function fetchItems() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestItems());

    return fetch(API_URL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(receiveItems(json)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(failFetchItems()))
  };
};
```

I guess I will have to use Promises.

Comment: _"I guess I will have to use Promises."_ Your code already uses `Promise`

Comment: What is the expected result of this syntax `return dispatch => {`?

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like you're using `redux-thunk`. I don't think that's the good way to update the state. You can rely your `refreshing` state to be moved at the reducer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the `async/await` notation to make your code asynchronous ?
`async/await` allows you to suspend code execution until a `Promise` is settled, if the awaited expression isn't a `Promise`, then its casted into a `Promise`.

```
onRefresh = async () => {
  await this.setState({ refreshing: true });
  await this.props.fetchItems();
  await this.setState({ refreshing: false });
}
```

Personnally, I've always been using this to make my code asynchronous.

Some links if you want to study this notation:

[Blog post about `async/await`](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)

[`async/await` explanation](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `fetchItems` returns a promise (it looks like it does), and then call the second `setState` like this:

```
this.props.fetchItems().then(() => this.setState({refreshing: false}))
```